# How do I make a Conan test package require the package that it is testing? Specifically if the package version is dynamic?

Tags: python, c++, cmake, conan

let's say I have a package:

```
from conans import ConanFile

class MainLibraryPackage(ConanFile):
    name = 'main'
    description = 'stub'

    def set_version(self):
        self.version = customFunctionToGetVersion()
    ...
```

And I have a test package for it:

```
import os
from conans import ConanFile, CMake

class MainLibraryTests(ConanFile):
    """
    Conan recipe to run C++ tests for main library
    """

    settings = 'arch', 'build_type', 'os', 'compiler'
    generators = "cmake"

    def requirements(self):
        self.requires("gtest/1.12.1")
        self.requires(<my main library, somehow?>)

    def build(self):
        cmake = CMake(self)
        cmake.configure()
        cmake.build()

    def test(self):
        print("THIS IS A TEST OF THE TEST")
        if not tools.cross_building(self):
            os.chdir("bin")
            self.run(".%smain_tests" % os.sep)
```

How do I actually add the main package as a requirement? And if I do so, will that properly populate the `CONAN_LIBS` variable in the `CMakeLists.txt` for my test package? Thanks!

Comment: Some comments: you are using the legacy ``CMake`` integrations, besides the very good response below, I'd also recommend to use the ``conan new hello/0.1 -m=cmake_lib`` to have a working project template that already uses the new integrations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the Conan Community!

Your answer depends on which Conan version are you running.

For Conan 1.x, your package is automatically consumed by the test package if you run `conan create` command. However, if you want to develop step-by-step and run `conan test test_package <reference>` you need to pass the reference by command line. Still, you don't need to add your package as a requirement, for both cases, Conan resolves it automatically.

However, Conan 2.x is still in Beta, but very close to be released as stable.
On Conan 2.x, the test package will no longer manage your package automatically, you will need to declare as a requirement, exactly what are you doing in your question. And, this behavior is compatible with Conan 1.x, if you add the attribute `test_type = "explicit"` in the `test_package/conanfile.py`

So answering your question, you should use:

```
self.requires(self.tested_reference_str)
```

The `self.tested_reference_str` will resolve your package reference automatically for you, so you don't need to care about which version or name, it will the same used by your Conan command.

For further information, I recommend you reading the official documentation:

The getting started there is section about testing your package: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/creating_packages/getting_started.html#getting-started

How to prepare your test_package for Conan 2.x: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/migrating_to_2.0/recipes.html#changes-in-the-test-package-recipe

Comment: A wonderfully helpful and thorough answer! Thank you so much.